# Python: Remove selected whitespace from string

Tags: python

I want to remove some of the selected whitespace in a string.
Lets say I have a index of whitespace to remove:

```
w_index = [1,3]
```

And a string:

```
str = 'a b c d'
```

What I need is to remove first and third whitespaces so the end result is:

```
str = 'ab cd'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Remember: strings are immutable in python.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Input
w_index = [1,3]
str = 'a b c d'

# Solution
space_pos = [p for p in range(len(str)) if str[p]==' ']
w_pos = [space_pos[x-1] for x in w_index]
''.join(str[x+1:y] for x,y in zip([-1]+w_pos, w_pos+[len(str)]))

# result: 'ab cd'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a string in python. What you have to do is create a new string and concatenate the substrings. You loop over the index array and create a substring from the start to the first index (exclusive), the first+1 to the second and so on. At the end you combine the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Python indexing starts from zero so I adjusted your w_index list.

```
w_index = [0,2]
```

Also, `str` is a special name in Python so I renamed your string variable.

```
string = 'a b c d'
```

Now create a new list `wpos` that gives the position of each whitespace in `string`.

```
wpos = [i for (i, char) in enumerate(str) if char == ' ']

print "wpos:", wpos
```

**Output:**

```
>> wpos: [1, 3, 5]
```

We can then loop through w_index in reverse and remove the whitespace by it's position. We can't `pop()` a string like we can a list, so split the string in two and combine it back together to make a new string.

```
for i in w_index[::-1]:
    pos = wpos[i]
    string = string[:pos] + string[(pos+1):]
print string
```

**Output:**

```
>> ab cd
```

Comment: Note: this solution is *much* slower than my solution, especially for large strings. It took 0.47 s for my script to remove 250,000 spaces from a 1,000,000 characters string, while it took your script 101 s to do the same task. More than 200 times slower! This is because your script creates two large strings in a cycle, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes of course it is slower. If you have large strings to work on, your method is faster. My answer is easier for a beginner to understand with intermediate steps to explain what is happening.